# Launch App directly on push iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications, pushkit

Can I launch app on push received, without tapping on push notification ?

Example case for such behaviour : show incoming call screen for voip app when app is in background.

As I know it's not possible with APNs push notifications, but in iOS 8, Apple introduced PushKit framework with Voip push type, and as I understand, I can have my desired behaviour with them.

Comment: No you can't. No such function to do so.

Comment: I haven't read about PushKit, but from a user's perspective it would be **_very_** annoying if an app could launch itself like that, without user interaction. I really hope there is no answer to your question.

Comment: @NicolasMiari I can have such behaviour on Android and all Android Voip apps do so, and I think its comfortable to see call screen when you have incoming voip call (as you see call screen on regular call).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not allowed at all nor is it likely to be a feature that Apple would introduce.

Comment: Please explain me [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html)
>There are many advantages to using PushKit to receive VoIP pushes:
>Unlike standard push notifications, which the user must respond to before >your app can perform an action, VoIP pushes go straight to your app for >processing.
>Your app is given runtime to process a push, even if your app is operating >in the background.

Comment: That's only available for VoIP applications not for other apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can only receive payload of notification on which user tapped or selected from the notification center.

**But there is a way, using that you can process your every push notification. add key content-available with value 1 in to your aps dictionary.**

so it will look like,

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Game Request",
            "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
        },
        "badge" : 5
        "content-available" : 1
    }
}
```

If iOS system detects pushNotification with this key having value 1, it will call `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` of your appDelegate.

Comment: Last line of your answer **it will call `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` of your appDelegate** Does that mean I can launch my app?

Comment: app will be launched in the background and above method is called

Comment: ANd if I want to get my app open in foreground i.e. phone screen? Is there any hack for that?

Comment: No You can't open app in forground when receive push, because push is only used to inform the user

Comment: Seems like developers are slave of iOS. Can't do anything outside the scope.. Hahaha

Answer (score 0):

No, It will in all probability never be a feature.
Even if you (assume) technically introduce it, apple will block your app now.

> Pushkit is introduced only for receiving VoIP calls (obviously needed there). Thats it. For
>   generic apps, it is not present.